# how to have one force field influence on 2 collection?

Tags: objects, collections, force-fields

[image]
I am trying to make a tornado. I want to make a force field influences two different collections of particles.I have separated different force fields by collections but now I want a specific force,to influence both my collections. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic way to affect a force field to an emitter: Put your force field into a collection (let's call the collection *Force*), select your emitter and in the *Properties panel > Particle > Field Weights > Effector Collection*, choose the collection called *Force*. Do the same for the other emitters. It seems a bit buggy so if it doesn't work, remove the *Effector Collection* and select it again (or tweak some values in the particle settings).

If the emitter has no *Effector Collection*, all the force fields of the 3D scene will affect it.

**If your 2 emitters have 2 different effector collections and you want to affect one force field to both these 2 objects**, then put your force field into both these 2 collections (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Link to Collection*).

[image]